# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar los objetos duplicados de un array y añadir una unidad en un carrito de compra?

Tags: javascript, array, json, ordenamiento, busqueda

intento de saber como puedo buscar los objetos duplicados en un arreglo y poder seleccionar los duplicados, sumar los valores de unidad y dejarlo como un elemento nuevo dentro del mismo array pero con la unidad sumada de los duplicados.

```
var arregllo = [
{
    "plato": "Fresa",
    "matricula": "OTJQXO7AAD",
    "unidades": "1",
    "hash": "1447494199"
    "estado": "procesado"
},
{
    "plato": "Empanada",
    "matricula": "RAIMWQ5HUI",
    "unidades": "1",
    "hash": "1452590733",
    "estado": "procesado"
},
{
    "plato": "Empanada",
    "matricula": "RAIMWQ5HUI",
    "unidades": "1",
    "hash": "1451494976",
    "estado": "procesado"
},
{
    "plato": "Carrillada",
    "matricula": "XBCQDQ1MF4",
    "unidades": "1"
    "hash": "2090733504"
},
{
    "plato": "Carrillada",
    "matricula": "XBCQDQ1MF4",
    "unidades": "1",
    "hash": "2090733504"
},
{
    "plato": "Fresa",
    "matricula": "OTJQXO7AAD",
    "unidades": "1",       
    "hash": "1447494199"
}]
```

**Los datos que deben coincidir deben ser la matricula y el número HASH**. Ya que lo que quiero conseguir que el objeto con misma matricula y distinto hash se interpreta que es distinto, pero con mismo hash y matricula son completamente iguales, y a eso es lo que quiero sumar una unidad más en el próximo array.

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Quiero saber como puedo encontrar los objetos duplicados y, de esos objetos duplicados sumar su unidad para que en vez de dos objetos iguales solo aparezca uno con unidad en dos. Pero quiero hacer coincidir la matrícula y el hash de los objetos

Comment: Hola Daniel, en stackoverflow tenemos ganas de ayudar pero no de hacer todo el trabajo por ti, intenta resolver el problema por ti mismo y actualiza la pregunta con el código de tu intento

Comment: Hola Ivan, solo intento de saber que debo usar, si un .find() u otra función distinta, obvio no busco que me hagan el trabajo pero llevo horas intentado solucionarlo. He probado con un .find() pero solo puedo meter un parámetro y no un segundo parámetro. Pero gracias!

Comment: basicamente necesitas que al agregar un elemento al carrito se ejecute una funcion, que reciba por parametro el hash del producto. Luego con un forEach podes recorrer todo el carrito, y en cada objeto, consultas si el hash coincide con el parametro. Si luego de recorrer todo el array, no encontro el hash, agrega el objeto con cantidad 1. Si en cambio, lo encuentra en algun momento, deberias modificar el objeto donde lo encontro. Como? A unidad lo pasas a numero (esta en string), le sumas 1, volves a pasar el resultado a string y lo pones en la propiedad ``unidad``

Comment: @DanielGonzalezPitt si intentas eso y no te sale, pega el codigo en tu pregunta y alguien te lo va a solucionar. Asi, pidiendo una solucion sin haber intentado nada, lo dudo mucho, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Quizá esto te sirva, lo hice con funciones:

```js
var arreglo = [
{
    "plato": "Fresa",
    "matricula": "OTJQXO7AAD",
    "unidades": "1",
    "hash": "1447494199",
    "estado": "procesado"
},
{
    "plato": "Empanada",
    "matricula": "RAIMWQ5HUI",
    "unidades": "1",
    "hash": "1452590733",
    "estado": "procesado"
},
{
    "plato": "Empanada",
    "matricula": "RAIMWQ5HUI",
    "unidades": "1",
    "hash": "1451494976",
    "estado": "procesado"
},
{
    "plato": "Carrillada",
    "matricula": "XBCQDQ1MF4",
    "unidades": "1",
    "hash": "2090733504"
},
{
    "plato": "Carrillada",
    "matricula": "XBCQDQ1MF4",
    "unidades": "1",
    "hash": "2090733504"
},
{
    "plato": "Fresa",
    "matricula": "OTJQXO7AAD",
    "unidades": "1",       
    "hash": "1447494199"
}]

// Para duplicados: 

function encontrarDuplicados(array) {
    
    array_duplicados = []
    
    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i+1] == undefined) {
            break
        }
        else {
            if(array[i].matricula == array[i+1].matricula && 
                array[i].hash == array[i+1].hash) {
                    array_duplicados.push(Object.assign({},array[i]))
                    array_duplicados.push(Object.assign({},array[i+1]))
                }
        }
    }
    
    return array_duplicados
}

duplicados_encontrados = encontrarDuplicados(arreglo) 
arreglo.push(duplicados_encontrados[0])

let suma = 0
duplicados_encontrados.forEach(item => suma += parseInt(item.unidades))

arreglo.at(-1).unidades = String(suma)
console.log(arreglo)
```